# NodeJS + Express + Handlebars - failed to locate view "index.html"

Tags: templates, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have been playing a bit with Node.js.  I recently started toying with Express and have been setting up a basic app.  I wanted to use Handlebars as my view templating engine, but am hitting a wall - failed to locate view "index.html"

I have index.html in the same directory as app.js and and so I would think the code below would have no problem locating index.html...

I have searched around, but it would seem that comprehensive examples of anything aside from jade are rare... Anyone have experience with this combo?

Thanks in advance!

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set("view options", { layout: false }) 
});



app.get('/', function(req, res){

    var data = {
        name: "Ford Prefect",
        home: "a small planet somewhere in the vicinity of Betelgeuse"
    }

    res.render('index.html', data);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Update:**

I was missing:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
app.register('.html', require('handlebars'));
```

in my config...  it would seem that the register of '.html' is quite important as it specifies the handlebars association with .html...

I hope this helps someone...

Because I am a SO noob, I can't answer my own question for 7 hrs, but if anyone needs the complete working example, I can post tomorrow...

Comment: You may consider to name your files .handlebars instead of .html to make it obvious it's not a plain html file.  Soon [.hbs](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/174) might work too?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, it will look in a folder called `views` from the directory the script is. If you use a different dir you must specify it.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Express should also tell you more information about where it's trying to find the view, that should help you know exactly where it's looking.

Comment: Exactly. Truth told, this conclusion was arrived at in two steps for me - line 1 and then line 2 in the Update... First I discovered line 1, which lead me to encounter 

    Error: Cannot find module 'html'

which, as the story goes, line 2 resolved :) Hope my folly helps someone.