# TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'register'

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to use handlebars with nodejs and I get this error "TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'register'". Below is the code for the nodejs. The same code seems to have worked for other people since it's pretty much a copy paste of [NodeJS + Express + Handlebars - failed to locate view "index.html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814437/nodejs-express-handlebars-failed-to-locate-view-index-html). P.S. I am new to nodejs and trying to get a feel for it and am already used to handlebars.

```
//Load Modules
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

var app = express();

// Configuration
app.configure( function() {
    app.register('.html', handlebars);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set("view options", { layout: false });    
});

// Routes
app.get('/:first/:last', function(req, res) {
    var data = {title:req.param.first + " " + req.param.last};
    res.render("template/profilecard.html", data);
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("NodeJS Server Started");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express 3.0 changed the app.register to app.engine.  [Migrating to Express.js 3.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)

> Some template engines do not follow this convention, the consolidate.js library was created to map all of node's popular template engines to follow this convention, thus allowing them to work seemlessly within Express.

npm install consolidate

Try the following:

```
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.configure( function() {

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set("view options", { layout: false }); 
    app.engine('.html', engines.handlebars);
});
```

Comment: I haven't use handlebars, but I see there is https://github.com/donpark/hbs.  This may actually be a better solution.  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');  and    app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);

Comment: Your answer doesn't work, it can't seem to find the file, but it didn't give an error other then that, however the comment you left does work (I had actually already fixed this earlier and wasn't able to answer it here since I had no internet connection until now). Thanks though!

Comment: actually it does work, just needed the file extension on the file name unlike when I use hbs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GpSsbqXv Full/Fixed code for anyone who looks at this post, so that it's a little easier to understand.